# Node.js script not getting connected to Mongodb database in localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have following test code to run mongodb along with node.js while creating rest api

```
MONGO.JS 

var mongoose    =   require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/smartRideDb');
// create instance of Schema
var mongoSchema =   mongoose.Schema;
// create schema
var userSchema  = {
    "id"       : String,
    "email"    : String,
    "password" : String
};
// create model if not exists.
module.exports = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);
```

index.js is defined as

```
var mongoOp =   require("./models/mongo");
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router     = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended" : false}));

app.use('/' , router);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/**
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
// Generic error handler used by all endpoints.
function handleError(res, reason, message, code) 
{
  console.log("ERROR: " + reason);
  res.status(code || 500).json({"error": message});
}

/**
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
router.get("/",function(req,res)
{
    res.json({"error" : false,"message" : "Hello World"});
});


//route() will allow you to use same path for different HTTP operation.
//So if you have same URL but with different HTTP OP such as POST,GET etc
//Then use route() to remove redundant code.

router.route("/users").get(function(req, res)
{
    var response = {};
    mongoOp.find({},function(err,data)
    {
        if(err) 
        {
            response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
        }
        else 
        {
            response = {"error" : false,"message" : data};
        }

        res.json(response);
    });
});


app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening to PORT " + port);
```

When i run i get this error

```
Muhammads-MBP:Api Umar$ node index.js
Listening to PORT 3000

/Users/Umar/Desktop/Projects On List Data/Creative Studios/School Ride/Api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
```

Why is mongodb not gett

Comment: can you telnet to with command : `telnet 127.0.0.1 17027` ?

Comment: Nop @ThanhNguyenVan , i am using mac

Comment: Just curious if you started your mongod service? I have this ECONNREFUSED  error always when i forgot to turn on. or can you restart your mongo service? You can also open a terminal, simply run `mongo` and see if you're able to connect

Comment: @ChinKang writing only mongo gives me no command found. I am using moongose

Comment: moongose is the JS connector to the mongoDB. `mongo` is the CLI comes together with the installation of MongoDB, so you should be able to run it on mac if you have mongo installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try to ensure the MongoDB has properly setup first by following

1. MongoDB is installed successfully ([OSX guide here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/))
2. Run `mongod` in terminal after installed to run the MongoDB
3. Run `mongo` in another terminal, and you should be able to see something similar.

.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: test
```

Comment: ok thanks that worked, i hadn't specifically installed mongodb, i thought moongose does that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the connection to mongo before app.listen, mongoose open a pool of connections by default for attend the requests

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("Listening to PORT " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most common troubleshooting steps:

1. Configured localhost incorrectly somewhere, so try changing your connection string to mongodb://localhost:27017/smartRideDb.
2. Check if mongod is running at that port.
3. Check if some other process is using that port.

Comment: how to check if mongod is running at that port and if not how to run it?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Open your terminal and type `mongo`. See what happens

Comment: Just go to your terminal and type `mongo`. By default it uses that port, so if it goes to the mongo shell then you know mongod is running. Otherwise you can use `ps -ef | grep mongo` to check it.